# How to have fun in Bouillon, Belgium

Tags: belgium

I'm going to Bouillon, Belgium with seven friends for some kayaking. Anybody here knows of other fun things to do on the trip?

Comment: Reading a book sounds fun...

Comment: I would make a point of finding a place that serves a good warm broth.

Comment: @Karlson I should have added there would be the 8 of us...

Comment: @MastaBaba Was that a play on words or do they actually serve amazing broth in Bouillon and hence the name?

Comment: @PeterRaeves No.  You should add what "other fun" you would consider.

Comment: @Karlson No I shouldn't, because reading when being with friends, would be rather rude.

Comment: @PeterRaeves Yes.  You should.  While reading a book isn't necessarily a fun activity for some if you and your friends are members of book club that might be something for you to do.  And while this is an exaggeration your question is asking for an opinion from the answerer without any criteria by which to evaluate ones answer so my suggestion would be just as valid as any other.

Comment: @PeterRaeves: It was a linguistic joke. To the extent that if I'd be going to Bouillon I would most certainly find a place that serves a warm broth. What else is such a name good for? Additionally, there are the nearby towns of Bastogne (cookies of the same name exist) and Spa (soda water).

Comment: @Karlson At the time of writing I had indeed forgotten about the fact that you shouldn't ask for suggestions on SE. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bouillon is a fairly quiet town, but the place I would recommend is the brewery, quite small it produces three beers, but also has a shop that sells over 300 beers

There is also an animal park / trail, but I have not visited it

Some more information on the town is here on the visit Belgium website

http://www.visitbelgium.com/index.php?page=bouillon-2